# SQL Getting value in same row as another known value

Tags: sql

Best way is to explain in pseudo code

```
How do I Get x,
When table1.activity == "some_string" 
Then x = table1.line_number in that same row.
```

I'm doing an `INNER JOIN` and I'm doing checks on table 2. Basically I don't want to join that row if `table1.activity == "some_string"`

Comment: best way is to show your actual code

Comment: You hadn't mentioned `table2` in your pseudo code.

Comment: Some sample data too, and expected result!

Answer (score 0):

well it's not mentioned **table2** in your pseudo code
but you could filter values in the inner join ON statement or WHERE statement of the query. It depends what you want By example, (In where Section)

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 AS pivot
 INNER JOIN table2 USING(id)
 WHERE pivot.activity <>'not_want_these_kind_of_Records';
```

Or in ON Section

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS pivot
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id=pivot.id 
 AND t2.activity <>'not_want_these_kind_of_Records';
```

The second One filter the results before join to the pivot table

Regards